# Two UK visas in different passports?

Tags: visas, uk, dual-nationality

I have a valid Standard Visitor UK visa for several years. But I also must attend a study course for 3 months in the UK, and organisers informed me that I must have a short term student visa. If I reapply for a student visa with this passport my longer Standard Visitor visa can be canceled. And I don't want this. Another reason, is that I need my passport for traveling while having other passport in the UK migration for several weeks waiting for a decision.

I also have a second passport, a different nationality and slightly different name. **Can I apply for a student visa with other passport, and have a valid Standard Visitor in different passport simultaneously?**

Of course I would submit copies of my two passports with my application. And an officer may see that I, as a person of another nationality, already have a visa, though a different type.

Comment: I made clarifications that I have slightly different name in other my passport and therefore I can be a different person. And It is not dual-nationality, but two different nationalities.

Comment: `I would submit copies of my two passports with my application` You do realize that your picture will be in the database, your DoB, your place of birth and other information. If data from both applications match up, I will be pretty sure alarm bells will start ringing in the ECO;'s head. I am not sure about the legalities but same person having 2 overlapping visas  on 2 different passports will pass the ECO ? But you can try.

Comment: I have to be honest in my application. If I do not report that I have different passport in application, this could be suspicious.